# How to run another app from current process without binding with it output?

Tags: d, spawn

Is there any way to run an app from the main app as a separate process without binding it's output?

The situation is next. I am doing simple micros-service monitor. Every 10 minutes it checks if the other 5 micro-services are working. If not, it should start them. The problem that when I am using `spawnProcess` it's output is binding with MonitorApp. But I do not want it. I need to just run them as separate threads.

Important moment I need a way to get the PID of every micro-service running.

Now if I am closing MonitorApp it's children are dying. So I think that they shouldn't be children, but separate processes.

https://dlang.org/phobos/std_process.html

Comment: What doe you mean by "binding with" on the output? The default params of spawnProcess inherit the same output as the parent.

Comment: I need do not inherit output by parent. And be free to exit from parent by ctrl+с while children will continue work.

Comment: did you try passing `Config.detached` to `spawnProcess`?

Comment: So what should its std in/out go to instead?

Comment: What platform is this running on? Posix or Unix? Also, when you say "closing", do you mean sending Ctrl-C? How are you closing it?